# Connection problem with ethernet

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I have installed ubuntu server 16.04 and I am now trying to connect it to the network with ethernet but I can't get to work. I am still new to Ubuntu server.

This is how the interfaces file looks like, (enp3s0 is my ehternet port and I added it to the file).

```
**# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#ethernet
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp**
```

Below is the result of `ifconfig`:

```
**enp3s0  Link encap: Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:16:ac:10:fd
        inet6 addr: fe80: :21f:16ff:feac:10fd/64 Scope: Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU: 1500 Metric: 1
        RX packets: 426 errors: 0 dropped: 102 overruns: 0 frame: 0
        TX packets: 240 errors: 0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 carrier: 0
        collisions: 0 txqueuelen: 1000
        RX bytes: 27876 (27.8 KB) TX bytes: 80952 (80.9 KB)
        Interrupt: 16


lo     Link encap: Local Loopback
       inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:255.0.0.0
       UP LOOBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
       RX packets:26160  errors: 0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 frame: 0
       TX packets:26160 errors: 0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 carrier: 0
       collisions: 0 txqueuelen: 1
       RX bytes: 1936576 (1.9 MB) TX bytes: 1936576 (1.9 MB)**
```

The result of `iwconfig` below:

```
**enp3s0  no wireless exstensions.
lo no wireless extensions**
```

if I try to ping the router it says

> connect: Network unreachable

I really don't know what to do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may already know `nmcli`. For an ethernet connection: `nmcli con add type ethernet ifname enp3s0 con-name enp3s0; nmcli con up id enp3s0`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I tried the command and it said the following, (I added sudo first to be safe): sudo:  nmcli: command not found. The program ´nmcli´ is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install network-manager. I tried it but it could not fetch all archives and tells me to try apt-get update or --fix-missing.

Comment: apt-get update didn't work, (Unable to locate package update). --fix-missing didn't work either, it filed to fetch the archives.